# Back referencing in a document?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, back-referencing

How can I produce a back reference in a LaTeX document, for linked references in a bibliography, or for links to figures, sections etc.?

I.e. linking from text to reference, and then from reference back to text. This is a common way to read.

Like in this example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors#Citations

Clicking the ^ in the citations list brings you back to the text. I find this a necessity.

Can someone give an example? Here is an example of the LaTex text I am using with reference links.

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\mathchardef\hyphenmathcode=\mathcode`\- % BJD added here 16.12.2020

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % BJD added here 14.8.2018
\usepackage{breqn}  % BJD added here 14.8.2018

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\newgeometry{asymmetric, centering}
\usepackage [english]{babel} % BJD added here
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes} % BJD added here
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % BJD 20.10.2018
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %BJD 20.10.2018
%\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption} %BJD 20.10.2018
%\MakeOuterQuote{"} % BJD added here
%% show notes and keys in the draft mode %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifoptionfinal{
    \usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
}{
    \usepackage[norefs, nocites]{refcheck}
    \usepackage{soul}
    %\providecommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily#1} %BJD 20.2.2020
    %\usepackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys} %BJD 20.2.2020
    \usepackage[bordercolor=white, color=white]{todonotes}
}
\usepackage{xfrac}  % BJD added here 15.8.2018
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts} % BJD added here 23.8.2018 
\usepackage{upgreek} % BJD added here 25.8.2018 

\usepackage{rotating, graphicx} % BJD added here 20.10.2018
\usepackage{tikz} % BJD added here 20.10.2018
\usepackage{blindtext} % BJD added here 20.10.2018
\usepackage{caption} % BJD added here 20.10.2018
%\usepackage{tikz} % BJD added here 20.10.2018
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
\usepackage{rotating} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
%\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
\usepackage{amsfonts} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
\usepackage{textcomp} % BJD added here 8.10.2023
\usepackage{nicefrac} % BJD added here 8.10.2023

\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu} % BJD added here 16.9.2023

%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
%\usepackage{array} % BJD added here 16.9.2023
%------------BJD 15.8.2018-----------------------
\makeatletter
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
        \baselineskip14\p@\relax
        \bfseries
        \uppercasenonmath\@title
        \@title
        \ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else
        \\[1ex]\uppercasenonmath\@subtitle
        \footnotesize\mdseries\@subtitle
        \fi
    \end{center}%
}
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\@subtitle{}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{
%   defaultdialect=[Visual]Basic
%   ,frameround=fttt
%   ,language=SQL
%   ,numbers=left
%   ,breaklines=true
%   ,showstringspaces=false
%   ,basicstyle=\small
%}
%---------------BJD added 16.12.2020--------------------
% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{10} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{10}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
%\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
%       language=Python,
%       basicstyle=\ttm,
%       otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
%       keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
%       emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
%       emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
%       stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
%       frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
%       showstringspaces=false            % 
%}}

\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
        language=Python,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
        keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
        emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
        emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
        stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
        frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
        showstringspaces=false            % 
}}

% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
    \pythonstyle
    \lstset{#1}
}
{}

% Python for external files
\newcommand\pythonexternal[2][]{{
        \pythonstyle
        \lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}}

% Python for inline
\newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

%-------------------------------------------
% \let\origlstlisting=\lstlisting
%\let\endoriglstlisting=\endlstlisting
%\renewenvironment{lstlisting}
%{\mathcode`\-=\hyphenmathcode
%   \everymath{}\mathsurround=0pt\origlstlisting}
%{\endoriglstlisting}
%-------------------end 16.12.2020--------------------------------------


%-------------------------------------------------
%******BJD change****************
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {/home/user/images/} }
%\graphicspath{ {/home/bjd/Downloads/} }
%******BJD change end****************
\newcommand{\HOX}[1]{\todo[noline, size=\footnotesize]{#1}}
\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{\hfill\todo[inline, bordercolor=black, color=green!10]{#1}}
%% HACK from Sec. 1.6.4 of the manual of todonotes package
\makeatletter\providecommand\@dotsep{5}\def\listtodoname{List of Todos}\def\listoftodos{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\@starttoc{tdo}\listtodoname\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}}\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% numbering %%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

%% definitions %%%%%%%%% 
\def\C{\mathbb C}
\def\R{\mathbb R}
\def\Q{\mathbb Q}
\def\Z{\mathbb Z}
\def\N{\mathbb N}

\def\p{\partial}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\newcommand{\pair}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1 \right\|}
%\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
%\def\inter{\text{int}}
%\let\dim\relax
%\DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{imakeidx} % BJD 23 Dec 2022
\makeindex   % BJD 23 Dec 2022

\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{rsfso} % BJD 1 Jan 2023
%\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,subentry,backend=biber]{biblatex} % BJD 24 Dec 2022
%\usepackage{hyperref} % BJD 24 Dec 2022
%\rfoot{Page \thepage}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\begin{document}
% Set the page style to "fancy"...
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\title{Warning without twoside}
%\author{Overleaf}
%\date{July 2022}
%\fancyhead[E]{Hello}% This triggers a warning!
%\fancyfoot[E]{\thepage}% This triggers a warning!


\begin{document}

The idea that process is the basis of physical existence has a long history in the philosophy of science beginning with ancient creation myths, proceeding to the surviving fragments of the teachings of Heraclitus.\cite{PL_GOTC}\cite{DAH} The renowned scientist and inventor Nikola Tesla commented about this view of nature writing:\cite{NT1}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

%Chapter 1

\bibitem{PL_GOTC} %ref 1
LaViolette, P. A. \textit{Genesis of the Cosmos}, (1st ed.: Beyond the Big Bang.)
Rochester, VT: Bear \& Co., 1995, 2004.

\bibitem{DAH} %ref 2
Hyland, D. A. \textit{The Origins of Philosophy}. New York: Putnam, 1973, p. 163.

\bibitem{NT1} %ref 3
Tesla, N. ``Man's greatest achievement.'' \textit{New York American}, July 6, 1930.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Also, see here in Overleaf: @ https://www.overleaf.com/project/6527e8b4ebfc3e15cec36092

Comment: The problem is the back reference is a one-to-many relation as more than one link can jump to this location. So how should LaTeX know from where you came? Use  Alt+left arrow to go back.

Comment: For bibliography, you can use biblatex that has a `backref=true` mechanism (see example here https://leo.colisson.me/articles/2022_-_PhD/PhD_Leo_Colisson.pdf). For theorem/proofs, you have my library proof-at-the-end that link theorem to the proof and the proof to the theorem. For arbitrary links, I guess it is possible to create a `\ref{}`-like command that adds a link anchor at the current position (see phantom section), and modify a macro with this link, and then create a command like`\backref{fig:foo}` that would just  create the backward link. Should be doable.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! That's useful to know.

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/backref may be helpful, but you will find it easier if you use something like Biblatex/Biber or BibTeX to manage your bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

I found on my pdf document (for ubuntu system), it is "`Alt` + `P` / `backspace`" to return to the precious text page after a link jump. Also, see here:

@ https://superuser.com/questions/22786/back-button-of-adobe-pdf-reader-after-clicking-a-hyperlink-whose-target-is-on-th

On my ubuntu system pdf document, I went to: `Menu` - `keyboard shortcuts` - `previous page visited` (there's 3 pages of it).